# Annotation Detail View not Loading in Mapkit

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, mapkit

I have a Map that shows various pins based on the users location.  I can view the pins and there callouts without a problem.  When I press the detail disclosure button, my MapDetailInfo does not load.  Here is some of the code.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{
// Specify which MKPinAnnotationView to use for each annotation. 

MKPinAnnotationView *businessListingPin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"BLPin" ];

if (businessListingPin == nil)
{
    businessListingPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"BLPin"];
}
else
{
    businessListingPin.annotation = annotation;
}

// If the annotation is the user's location, don't show the callout and change the pin color
if(annotation == self.mapView.userLocation)
{
    businessListingPin.canShowCallout = NO;
    businessListingPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
}
else
{
    businessListingPin.canShowCallout = YES;
    businessListingPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    businessListingPin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

}

return businessListingPin;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
 annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
MapDetailInfo *abc = [[MapDetailInfo alloc]init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[nav pushViewController:abc animated:YES];
}
```

Not sure if it matters or not, but this is part of a tab bar application.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a UINavigationController (`UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];`) and then pushing your new VC onto that, but you never add that nav controller to the current view stack. Simply calling `init` doesn't add that navigation controller to the stack.

When you create your `UITabController`, you can create + use a navigation controller for each tab. Then you push the new VC onto *that* navigation controller.

Hope this helps.

** edit

If you've already got navigation controllers for all of your tabs, change your code to this:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view 
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    MapDetailInfo *abc = [[MapDetailInfo alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:abc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Understood... I have put a navigation controller on each tab.... I guess I am unsure of how to push the new VC on to that Navigation controller (sorry I am still pretty new to this)... thanks!

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:abc] I think.. your map VC should have a reference to its own nav controller

Comment: Got it to work.  Thanks!  I had the viewControllers a little mixed up.  Did some reordering and it work.